# Path to store SQLite database in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm trying to store a local SQLite database in the internal storage of the device. When I was using an emulator    , this:

```
static string dbName = "totems.sqlite";
string dbPath = Path.Combine (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString (), dbName);
```

worked fine. But when I tried to debug on my Nexus 5, it didn't work, because it doesn't have external storage. I searched where to store it so it could run on my Nexus as well. I replaced it with:

```
static string dbName = "totems.sqlite";
string dbPath = Path.Combine ("/data/data/com.companyname.totem/databases/", dbName);
```

But now it doesn't work on my Nexus 5 and it doesn't work on my emulator. It says it can't find the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but the old answer has a typo. The working syntax should be :

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DatabaseName.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using the following code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(System.Enviroment.GetFolderPath(System.Enviroment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "data.txt");
```

I think that should write into the internal storage like you want

Comment: This is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-MonoAndroid,Version%3Dv9.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8)

> `LocalApplicationData`: The directory that serves as a common
>   repository for application-specific data that is used by the current,
>   non-roaming user.
>
> `Personal`: The directory that serves as a common repository for
>   documents. This member is equivalent to MyDocuments.

From this I use:

```
var db_directory = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),"databases"))

var db_path = Path.Combine(db_directory,"data.db");
```

Also from this sample (XF)
[docs.com xamarin tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/local-database/?tutorial-step=2&tabs=vswin)

```
public static Database Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new Database(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "people.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
        }
```